# Laravel 5 - Skip password confirmation on Update [EDIT: FIREFOX is causing problems]

Tags: php, forms, laravel, firefox, passwords

I created some simple CMS with Laravel 5.2 and in the backend users can create & edit users. There is a simple form for that:

```
@section('content')
{!! Form::model($user, [
    'method' => $user->exists ? 'put':'post',
    'route' => $user->exists ? ['backend.users.update', $user->id] : ['backend.users.store'],
]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit($user->exists ? 'Save User' : 'Create New User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

When you create a new user - password must be confirmed.

But when you edit some user - **the problem is that you always have to confirm password**. For example, if I just change 'Name' - I still have to confirm password.

Here is my **Requests\UpdateUserRequest.php**:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'=>['required'],
        'email'=>['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email,'.$this->route('users')],
        'password' => ['required_with:password_confirmation', 'confirmed']
    ];
}
```

and here is **UserController.php**:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = $this->users->findOrFail($id);
    return view('backend.users.form', compact('user'));
}

public function update(Requests\UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->users->findOrFail($id);
    $user->fill($request->only('name', 'email', 'password'))->save();
    return redirect(route('backend.users.edit', $user->id))->with('status', 'User has been updated');
}
```

When you open the form for editing, it looks like this:

[image: Edit User Form]

As you can see - when I open edit form each field of the form has been filled except for Password Confirmation.

How can I solve this problem (If I don't change the password but other fields - I don't need to confirm password)?

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

### **EDIT:**

I have tried other browsers - field *Password* is empty and everything is working properly: For example, if I just change the Name field - I don't have to confirm password.

So, the field Password is filled (autocompleted?) by Firefox. `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work.

Comment: check out [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update) i definitely sure that you get you answer from here.

Comment: @utsav Now I think I realized what is causing the problem - Firefox autocompletes Password field (please see **EDITs** in my first post/question above), but don't know how to solve... `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work.

Comment: It's not necessary to initiate password input value because it's simply password ! So laravel does not consider it.

Answer (score -1):

Just force the 'password' and the 'password_confirmation' fields with an empty value. Like this:

```
Form::password('password', '', ['class'=>'form-control']);
```

So if the password and the password_confirmation remains empty Laravel will simple ignore the password field.

Comment: How is that different from `Form::password('password', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])`, which is the OPs current implementation?

Comment: @Hubber I've tried, and it's the same - when I open the edit form - each field of the form has been filled except for Password Confirmation (see the picture in my first post/question).

Comment: What version of Laravel did you use because FormBuilder doesn't exist any more in in Laravel 5.* . If you are using 4.2 than the password() doesn't show the value by default.

Comment: @Hubber I am using Laravel 5.2 with _illuminate/html_ component installed.

Comment: Try to use this: Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']); because password method accept only two parameters $name and $options

Comment: @Hubber Now I think I realized what is causing the problem - Firefox autocompletes Password field (please see **EDITs** in my first post/question above), but don't know how to solve... `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work.